# check if all properties are provided or all are not

Tags: javascript

`myobject` has 4 properties. If all of these properties have value (anything but null and undefined), `allow = true`
and if none of these properties have value (are null or undefined), `allow = true`, in any other situations `allow = false`

```
if (!Object.values(myobject).every(property => [null, undefined].includes(property)) &&
     Object.values(myobject).some(property => [null, undefined].includes(property))) {
allow = true
}
```

Is there any better way to reach this? (though this doesn't give me the right `allow`)

Comment: What do you mean by "provided"?

Comment: having a value (anything but null and undefined) @T.J.Crowder

Comment: `Object.values(obj).every(val => val != null);`

Comment: "Having a value" suggests that the property exists. Do you need to handle the case where it doesn't exist at all? (It would come back as `undefined` if you looked for it in that case.)

Comment: since I'm creating it, I'm sure the property exists. I just need to look for the value. @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, the problem with your original code is that you need `every` in both halves of it, not `some` in the second half:

```
if (Object.values(myobject).every(v => v == null) ||
    Object.values(myobject).every(v => v != null)) {
    allow = true;
}
```

(`== null`/`!= null` checks for `null` and `undefined`.)

It also does't set `allow` to `false` if there's no match, so it'll keep whatever previous value it had. To ensure it's set:

```
allow = Object.values(myobject).every(v => v == null) ||
        Object.values(myobject).every(v => v != null);
```

Live Example:

```js
function check(label, myobject) {
    const allow = Object.values(myobject).every(v => v == null) ||
            Object.values(myobject).every(v => v != null);
    console.log(label, allow);
}

check("all", {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4});
check("none", {a: null, b: undefined, c: null, d: undefined});
check("mix", {a: 1, b: undefined, c: null, d: undefined});
```

I think I'd probably do it differently (probably explicitly checking each property by name, though it depends a lot on context), but figured it would be useful to know what was wrong with the original.

Comment: I really appreciate your time but this still gives me `allow = false` when all the properties have value

Comment: @Qiimiia - The code in the answer gives `allow = true` when all of the properties have a value other than `null` or `undefined`. I've added a live example showing that it does return `true` when all the properties are `null` or `undefined`, or when none of them is, but `false` if only some of them are.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was that beside `null` and `undefined`, I had to look for empty string also. Thanks again. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the values, and you're looking for either zero or all the properties being set:

```js
const isAllOrNone = (obj) => {
   const values = Object.values(obj);
   const notSet = values.filter(val => [null,undefined].includes(val));
   return notSet.length == 0 || notSet.length == values.length;
}

console.log(isAllOrNone({x:"foo",y:"bar"}));
console.log(isAllOrNone({x:"foo",y:null}));
console.log(isAllOrNone({x:undefined,y:null}));
```

Comment: Someone wish to comment on the DV? My code does exactly what is asked in the question AFAICS

Comment: I'm not seeing the reason for it either, unless it's the possibility of properties not existing at all. I asked the OP about that but they haven't replied yet.

Comment: OK, thanks @T.J.Crowder - Thought there was something I missed. Yeah there is a deficiency in `Object.values` but I just started with the OP's existing code which presumably does some of what they wanted.

Comment: They've now confirmed that they know the properties exist.